# how do i convert ANSII to DEC

Tags: php, int, varchar

base on this formula `$tag= pack("H*",dechex(1146046298));` output is DOGZ

now i need the reverse of that formula. once i input DOGZ the output must be 1146046298

Comment: yes have tried $tag = unpack("H*",hexdec('DOGZ')); result was 3133

Comment: Did you try doing them in the correct order?

Comment: what do u mean correct order sir

Comment: Decode order: first `dechex`, then `pack`. The reverse of that is first `unpack`, then `hexdec`...

Comment: can u give the the ordered syntax pls i really dont know how to use that pack and unpack + decoding thanks

Comment: @deceze i already did that sir >>> unpack("H*",hexdec('DOGZ')); still not working

Answer (score 0):

> > Decode order: first `dechex`, then `pack`. The reverse of that is first `unpack`, then `hexdec`...
>
> i already did that sir >>> unpack("H*",hexdec('DOGZ')); still not working

No, the reverse of `pack('H*', dechex(1146046298))` is `hexdec(unpack('H*', 'DOGZ'))`. And since `unpack` results in an array, you also need to get the value from the array. So:

```
hexdec(current(unpack('H*', 'DOGZ')))
```